# Rounding price in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, price

I'm trying to round up prices in WC, on checkuot page, if product price is 70,55 there is TAX (+20%) = 14,11

So, how to round final price to 14.10, or to 14.15 if its closer to 15, just on 5 or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'your_custom_function_name_here' );` and then write a custom function like this below to round to nearest 5 cents ... i.e 0.05 or 0.10:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'my_custom_roundoff' );
function my_custom_roundoff( $total ) {
$round_num = round($total / 0.05) * 0.05;
$total = number_format($round_num, 2); // this is required for showing zero in the last decimal
return $total;
}
```